# Ubuntu 16.04.1 IP address change

Tags: server, 16.04, ip

How do I change the IP address from DHCP to my static IP (reserved for this server)?

What are the exact commands to get into the configurattion interface?

Comment: Do you use Network Manager or `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces do not work --> command not found @Melebius

Comment: This is a configuration file (this applies for the whole `/etc` folder), not a command.

Comment: but how do i change it what arethe "commands" to do that ? @Melebius

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup a static IP for network-manager in Virtual Box on Ubuntu Server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/246077/how-to-setup-a-static-ip-for-network-manager-in-virtual-box-on-ubuntu-server)

Comment: I tried to find a Network Manager solution but it looks like editing `/etc/network/interfaces` is the preferred option.

Comment: Is there a router between your Ubuntu PC and Internet?

Comment: @SpasSpasov no i dont have a rooter i got my internet from the cloudsXD jes there is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. However, since you need to change the IP address to static,  the only way is to set-up a manual/static IP editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. for that you need to edit the **interfaces** file with;

```
sudo nano /etc/network/intarfaces
```

You'll ideally see something like;

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Replace it with;

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask x.x.x.x
gateway x.x.x.x
```

Moving further, if you have or require domain to be resolved along with DNS servers, you may add few more lines to the file, similar to;

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address x.x.x.x
netmask x.x.x.x
gateway x.x.x.x
dns-search example.com
dns-nameservers x.x.x.x x.x.x.x
```

Please note, there are two sets of `x.x.x.x` within the **DNS** name servers (Primary and Secondary) with a space. You may use one pair or both depending on your requirement.

To save the file select <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, -> enter and exit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

And then just to be sure, simple restart the interface with;

```
sudo ifdown eth0           # wait for sometime
sudo ifup eth0             # and then issue this to restart
```

Also, as a final step, simply type below to confirm the interface change;

```
ifconfig -a
```

## Alternative way;

Refer to your server or the device which responds to DHCP requests and add a reservation, in case if you do not like to play with the server, files.. etc.

In order to get the MAC address for reservation, simply check the interface information with a;

```
ifconfig eth0                 # or type ifconfig -a
```

which should ideally display something similar to below;

```
ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:c5:4a:16:5a  
          inet addr:10.0.0.100  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:c5ff:fe4a:165a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:466475604 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:403172654 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2574778386 (2.5 GB)  TX bytes:1618367329 (1.6 GB)
          Interrupt:16
```

Where you see the `HWaddr 00:15:c5:4a:16:5a` and assign it to the DHCP reservation.

Hope this helps!

More: **[Networking Configuration Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html)**