# Ubuntu 23.04: Static ip in interfaces does not persist

Tags: networking, virtualbox-networking

I can't assign a static ip in Ubuntu to get host-only network up and running, probably something simple

VirtualBox on windows 10 host, ubuntu server 23.04 as guest, no GUI installed on the guest
Host-Only network enabled, no DHCP
Network address: 192.168.56.1
This will be a testbed for private NET 7-8 MVC deployment

Access to internet from the guest is fine
I only need to access the guest from actual host, not LAN

By using the command `ifconfig -a`
I have found the interface name enp0s8 I should use

Temp assigment is fine
`ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.56.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`
I can reach NGINX default page from the host
Also `ifconfig` shows an ip assigned to enp0s8

I have edited the interfaces configuration
`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`
Added these lines

```
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
address 192.168.56.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.56.0
broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

But changes has no effect after reboot?

Network Manager is not installed
I have checked these guides and other questions, remarks, etc among a lot of stuff
https://gist.github.com/pjdietz/5768124
[How to setup a static IP for network-manager in Virtual Box on Ubuntu Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246077/how-to-setup-a-static-ip-for-network-manager-in-virtual-box-on-ubuntu-server?rq=1)

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces is deprecated. Please use netplan. You can find templates in /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples.

Comment: Thanks, I had come to just about the same conclusion